# How to connect WPF and WebAPI

Tags: wpf, asp.net-web-api, mvvm

I am creating a WPF Project with MVVM architecture. I've created the UI in one Visual Studio Project. I want to create WebAPI for the service creation for CRUD operation in a separate Visual Studio Project and I've to call the API methods in the WPF Project solution. How can I achieve it..?

Comment: You will get many samples if you simply google it.

Comment: this is a nearly broad topic. you need to manually send and receive your request to and from WebApi in your WPF application. you can Use RestSharp as a faster way to do this: http://restsharp.org/